# Find the index position of every element starting with `icon-`in a block of text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

What is the best way of looping through a text block to find the index position of every element starting with `icon-` using javascript or jQuery.
I also want to ignore any `<br>` tags in the index position calculation.

I have thought about using `substring` to find the position of the elements.

Here is an example text block

```
<div class="intro">
    Lorem dolor sit<br>
    <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur<br>
    adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span> lorem<br>
    ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

What I want to get out of this is how many characters in (minus white space and 
 tags) each `[class^=icon-]` is.

For example the first `[class^=icon-]` is 14 characters in

Thanks

Comment: What is your goal? What are the expected values?

Comment: What I want to get out is how many characters in (minus white space and <br> tags) each `[class^=icon-]` is. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what your looking for, it will find the index of the spans and ignore `br`

```
$(".intro [class^=icon-]").each(function() {
  var i = $(".intro *:not(br)").index(this)
  console.log(i)
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".intro [class^=icon-]").each(function() {
  var i = $(".intro *:not(br)").index(this)
  console.log(i)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  Lorem dolor sit<br>
  <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur<br> adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span> lorem<br> ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get the position of how many characters in it is within the text block, minus any white space and the <br> tags

Comment: @zizther You want to know how many character there is in the entire `intro` or in each `span` ?

Comment: What I want to get out of this is how many characters in (minus white space and 
tags) each [class^=icon-] is.

For example, the first [class^=icon-] is 14 characters in, the second [class^=icon-] is 46 characters in. This will be used to get the number position of the `<span>` tags. I thought about using `string.substring(0, $(".intro [class^=icon-]"));` But it needs some tidying up to get remove the`<br>` tags and spaces.

Comment: @zizther I dont follow, the spans are closed right after so they dont contain any letters `<span class="icon-pin"></span>`

Comment: Correct, they output an icon via CSS, and I need to get them to animate, so i need to find the position of the spans so I can put them into the array of characters, in the correct position. The 3rd party animation library does not support markup, so trying to manage this myself. If i can get the character count until each `[class^=icon-]`, that is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with jquery each like in the example

```js
$('[class^="icon-"]','.intro').each(function(index, element){
  console.log(index,element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
    Lorem dolor sit<br>
    <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur<br>
    adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span> lorem<br>
    ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use more than 1 classes on a element. So, You can keep using your "icon-" classes and add another one to capture them like "grabber" and now you are good to go. Just find the "grabber" classes with a for loop like;

```
var y = "number of grabbers";    
for(x:0;x<y;x++){
$('.grabber')[x].function.....
}
```

Comment: There is not much point of adding another class since it can easily be done without adding more data.

Comment: You are trying to prevent adding data but you are typing uncessary block of codes which is going to make harder to debugg soon enough. adding 1 word will prevent adding few block of js codes.